# insertion sort is not outputting right

Tags: java

My condition is not outputting the right numbers, the list is not changed trough the loop, this is my condition.

```
    if (j + 1 <= length)
    {
      insertionSort(arrayIn, indexIn + 1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: "is not working right": what exactly happens?

Comment: nothing actually happens to the list, it prints the same as the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition for the recursive call:

```
if (j + 1 <= length)
```

is wrong.

You should make the recursive call as long as `indexIn` is smaller than the last index of the array:

```
if (indexIn < length - 1) {
    insertionSort(arrayIn, indexIn + 1);
}
```

The rest of your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
public static void insertionSort(int arrayIn[], int indexIn) {
    if (indexIn <= 1)
        return;

    insertionSort(arrayIn, indexIn - 1);

    int last = arrayIn[indexIn - 1];
    int j = indexIn - 2;

    while (j >= 0 && arrayIn[j] > last) {
        arrayIn[j + 1] = arrayIn[j];
        j--;
    }
    arrayIn[j + 1] = last;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] array = {1, 3, 2, 4};
    insertionSort(array, array.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could a `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` operation, in your code,

Instead of,

```
if (j + 1 <= length)
{
  insertionSort(arrayIn, indexIn + 1);
}
```

Use this,

```
if (j + 1 < length)
{
    insertionSort(arrayIn, indexIn + 1);
}
```

And you have print your content of your array too,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[]{2, 3, 4, 1, 5};
    insertionSort(arr, 0);
    for(int i : arr)
    {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```